# A relaxed version of positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convex-optimization, positive-definite

From the definition, a Positive definite matrix is a symmetric matrix that has all of its eigenvalues $\lambda_i > 0$. And it is proved that a Matrix $A_{n\times n}$ is positive definite if and only if
$$ x^t A x > 0 \quad \forall x \in R^n $$

Then Sylvester's criterion provides the necessary and sufficient condition for $A$ to be postive definite which is $det{A^{(k)}_{k\times k}} > 0$ where $A^{(k)}_{k\times k}$ is the upper diagonal $k\times k$ sub-matrix of $A_{n\times n}$.

Now the relaxed problem is that $x_{n\times 1} > 0$ which is:
$$ x^t A x > 0 \quad \forall x \in R^n_{++}  .$$
In this case the matrix $A$ need not be positive definite to ensure above inequality holds. So is it possible to find a closed-form condition on matrix $A$ in this relaxed problem?

p.s. The algebraic interpretation of this is that, the matrix transformation $A$ only preserves the positive direction of eigenvector, if the eigenvector is in the $R^n_+$ cone.

Comment: Sylvester's criterion is only Positive definite. It does not work for positive semi-definite.

Comment: I corrected the issue by changing it to positive definite. The main notion of the problem still holds if we can find a closed form condition on $A$. Thanks.

Comment: If $A$ has all entries positive then $x^tAx>0$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}_+^n.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc is it a necessary and sufficient condition?

Comment: Certainly the condition is not necessary, as it is not necessary for standard positive definite matrices.

Comment: sylvester's criterion is necessary and sufficient. So I try to find a similar criterion for this relaxed case.